# Trying to plot data from a histogram csv file

Tags: python

I can't figure out how to get this working. I have measured the photon count rate on a single photon detector and got a range of values in the form of a histogram. I have got this data in a csv. file and the file only has one column of data about 5000 data points.

Anyone know how to get this plotted in python?

Comment: what kind of plot are you looking for? Please check out https://matplotlib.org/3.5.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.html

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -2):

Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.hist`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Example data generation
np.random.seed(0)
example_data = np.random.poisson(lam=5, size=5000)
# Convert the data into a DataFrame to simulate reading from a CSV
example_df = pd.DataFrame(example_data, columns=['Photon Count'])

# Plot histogram
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.hist(example_df['Photon Count'], bins=30, color='blue', edgecolor='black')
plt.title('Photon Count Histogram')
plt.xlabel('Photon Count')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image: photon count histogram]